# On the iPhone lock screen, how can I see just the number of unread mails?

Tags: iphone, email, screen-lock

As a Windows Phone user, I can see the *number* of new mails for an account on my lock screen.

I'd like to have the same effect on my iPhone, **without** seeing the mail's preview content. Is there a way to do this without jailbreaking the phone? Note that I realize I can have mails in my notifications area, but that involves seeing a mail preview.

Answer (score 1):

Settings, Notifications, Mail.

Change "Show Previews" (all the way at the bottom) to off.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn’t possible with the stock email client on iOS.

Comment: This is possible.  Simply disable "show preview" in Settings, Notifications, Mail.

Comment: The question was about the *number* of unread email. It’s definitely not possible to have the iOS stock email client show this on the lock screen.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon Plus, disabling “Show Previews” won’t hide the sender’s name (it will still read _John Doe 2m ago – Mail message – slide to read_)

Comment: I know, however it's as close as @Craig will be able to get without jailbreaking.